# Insert into Access Database won't commit

Tags: c#, oledb

I have this simple code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection();
        myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
        myConnection.Open();


        OleDbCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from Stand where Number='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        myConnection.Close();
        if (count == 1)
        {
            label1.Text = comboBox1.Text + " is Already Exist!";
        }
        else
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("insert into Stand ([Number]) values (3);",myConnection);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label1.Text = comboBox1.Text + " Added";
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

It returns **"Added"** (should work!), but when I open `mydb.mdb`, I see that nothing happened.

What could be the issue?

Comment: can you indent your code please..

Comment: comboBox1.Text ????, Shouldn't it be comboBox1.seletedItem.. Unless you name your textbox as comboBox1

Comment: Does it showing any exceptions in `catch` block?

Comment: Why you close connection after scalar query and than reopen it? Close when you finish. Second - insert has parameters but you don't **fill** this parameter? Why this parameter called **3**? Change scalar query to using parameters - it is good practice and avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @VVN no ... every thing works fine ... but it doesn't insert any thing !!

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus I've tried to close it with one close connection before, it gives me th same result .

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus : 3 is a random value just for test the insert

Comment: Did you debug your `insert` statement?

Comment: @Pankaj that was a try ... my problem is with insert statment

Comment: @VVN yes ... even i try with access directly and it works

Comment: @vvn when i added gridview and insert new record , autonumric digite show (-) :
example:
1    fires
2    sec
-7   3

1 and 2 is already exists ... when try to add 3 by grid view the autonumric shows -7

Comment: How many coloumns are there in your Table?Is there any `NOT NULL` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint?

Comment: @VVN : tow columns ... ID(autonumric) and Number (shorttext)

Comment: Did you tried to use quotes around the value?

Comment: yes ... also didn't work !

Comment: Change the datatype of the Number column to `Integer` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `;` in query, after completing query
update this

```
myConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("insert into Stand ([Number]) values (3)",myConnection);
```

or changing whole logic try this..

```
 try
        {

            using (var connection1 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=mydb.mdb"))
            {
                connection1.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

                Int32 count = 0; // (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                string Query = "select count(*) from Stand where Number='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
                using (cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, connection1))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    label1.Text = comboBox1.Text + " is Already Exist!";
                }
                else
                {
                    using (cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Stand ([Number]) values (@Value)", connection1))
                    {
                        //cmd.Connection = connection1;

                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", 3);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Always use parametrised queries.Your sql insert text doesn't use parameters.
This is the cause of **bugs** and **SqlInjection**

```
 myConnection.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("insert into Stand ([Number]) values(@test)",myConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test", 3);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```